# Font color not change in php intervention image manipulation

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm using PHP Intervention Image Library 2.x to put some text on an image. Everything works fine except for the font colour.

Font size, font, font angle, and the position change according to the given values, the only issue is it not takes the colour I'm setting in the callback function.

```
Image::configure(array('driver' => 'imagick'));
$img = Image::make(IMG . 'gold-full.jpg');
$font = new Intervention\Image\Imagick\Font();
            $img->text('Y. C. Perera', 1061, 1298.4, function($font) {
                $font->file('./img/ERASBD.TTF');
                $font->size(88);
                //$font->color('#fff');
                //$font->color('white');
                //$font->color(array(255,255,255)); 
                  $font->color('#ffffff');
            });
$img->save('./uploads/new-gold-full.jpg');
$img->destroy();
```

As I mentioned with the comment I tried all those types of settings for the color. but no luck.

Comment: It seems strange you are using a class ( Intervention ) to run a class ( Imagick ) to run Imagemagick.  Anyway have you tried the example on the Intervention examples page to seen if it works?